Cloudflare response headers not setting image/png
I have a Next app with an endpoint api/download?icon=UUID which downloads an png image.
In localhost everything is working fine, the problem is with the live version that uses cloudflare, the response headers are always set to text/plain;charset=UTF-8 even though I specified correct content type on my NextJS api endpoint:
import { type NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { downloadFileFromR2 } from '@/lib/s3';

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
    try {
        const fileName = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get('icon')!;
        const image = await downloadFileFromR2(fileName);

        return new Response(image, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'image/png',
                'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="${fileName}.png"`,
            },
        });
    } catch (error) {
        return new Response('Error downloading file');
    }
}


Any ideas what could be causing the issue?

It appears that Cloudflare detects the MIME type of the response and replaces the Content-Type header with its own detected value.
You can check the MIME type of the file by running the command:
file --mime-type ${fileName}.png

Also, as a workaround, you can use Cloudflare Transform Rule for override Content-Type, you can find full instruction here, and in this blogpost.
In a nutshell, you need:

Log in to the Cloudflare dashboard, and select your account and
website.
Go to Rules > Transform Rules.
Go to the Modify Response Header tab.
Select Create rule.
Under When incoming requests match, select if you wish to apply the rule to all incoming requests or only to requests that match a custom filter expression.
For Modify response header, select appropriate operation (Set static, Set dynamic, Add or Remove)
Enter the name of the HTTP response header to modify in Header name (Content-Type in your case)
To save and deploy your rule, select Deploy.

